# Apache Cordova App - update content using Javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, innerhtml

I am creating an app for the first time using Apache Cordova on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

The app is a simple timetable checker where a user logs in based on full name and date of birth and then their correct timetable is displayed.

I am using innerHTML to change the index page (the div displayDiv to be precise) to correspond to the variable, i so that 0 = Login Page, 1 = Show Period Page, 2 = Show Full Timetable Page

The problem is that I can't understand how the variable, i, keeps being initialised each time the innerHTML is changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TimetableTest1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/validateUser.js"></script>

    <div id="displayDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeContent(func) {
        var oldOnLoad = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
            window.onload = func
        } else {
            window.onload = function (i) {
                oldOnLoad(i);
                func(); 
            }
        }
    }

    changeContent(function(){

        var i; 

        if (i == undefined && window.onload!='function') {
            i = 0; 
        }
        var display = new Array();

        display[0] = '<h2>VCB TIMETABLE APP</h2><h3>Please enter your full name and date of birth to find out where your next class is</h3><form name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm();"><input type="text" maxlength="35" id="name"placeholder="Full name" /><br /><input type="text" maxlength="35" id="dob"placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" /><br /><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Log me in!" /><br /><input type="reset" name="Reset" /></form>'
        display[1] = '<h2>Where do I go?</h2>'
        display[2] = '<h2>Your full timetable</h2>'

        displayDiv.innerHTML = display[i];

        alert("changeContent final i = " + i);

    });

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### validateUser.js

```
function validateForm() {
    var nameStr = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var dobStr = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    if (nameStr == null || nameStr == "" || dobStr == null || dobStr == "") {

        alert("Name and DOB must be filled in");

    } else {
        i = 1;
        validateUser(nameStr, dobStr, i)
    }
}

function validateUser(nameStr, dobStr, i) {

    nameStr = nameStr.toUpperCase();

        alert("Hello " + nameStr + "\n validateUser content i: " + i);
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Ching Lun

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still having this problem unfortunately. 

I have no idea where to initialise i in order for it to not be initialised after the first onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!

The problem was with the submit button...

I changed it to "button" and simply called validateForm() with onclick

Answer (score 1):

You should move the declaration `var i;` outside of the function.

In your code, every time you execute the function to change the content, `i` is declared but not initialized so its value is `undefined`.

Thus, the condition `i == undefined` will be true.

Comment: I've tried that but its still reverting to undefined somehow. 

Thanks